# A doubt regarding the extension of Weierstrass factorization theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, polynomials, factoring

According to the Weierstrass factorization theorem, the sine function can be represented as a product of its factors:

$$\sin(x)-0=(x) \left(1 - \frac{x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 -  \frac{x}{2\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{2\pi} \right) \left(1 - \frac{x}{3\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{3\pi} \right) \cdots$$

Would it be wrong to extend this for any $\sin(x)-k=0$??

Is it valid to represent $$\sin(x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}) \left(1 - \frac{4x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 - \frac{4x}{3\pi} \right) \left(1 +  \frac{4x}{5\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{4x}{7\pi} \right) \cdots??$$

(Since, the factors of $\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ are: $\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\dfrac{-5\pi}{4},\dfrac{-7\pi}{4},\cdots$)

Or that, $$\sin(x)-\cos(x)=(-1) \left(1 - \frac{4x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{4x}{3\pi} \right) \left(1 -  \frac{4x}{5\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{4x}{7\pi} \right) \cdots??$$

(Since, the factors of $\sin(x)-\cos(x)$ are: $\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{-3\pi}{4},\dfrac{5\pi}{4},\dfrac{-7\pi}{4},\cdots$)

Comment: Yesss my bad, I made a few edits

Comment: You may find his theorem **weird** -- nevertheless his name is **Weierstrass** (or more precisely *Weierstraß*).

Comment: The Weirestrass factorization theorem applies to *every* entire function, including $\sin x-\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\sin x-\cos x$. One needs to check the details to see if your proposed factorizations are valid, but there is definitely some factorization.

Answer (score 1):

The Weierstraß product theorem is more complicated, it says, that for a set of set zeros and multiplicities ${a_k,n_k}$, without a finite limit point of the postions $a_k$, there exists   analytic functions

$$F_0(z) = (z-a_0)^{n_0}\prod_{m=1}^\infty \left( (1-\frac{z-a_0}{a_m-a_0}) \ e^{\text{A}_m}\right)^{n_m} $$

with

$$\text{A}_m = \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{k_n} \left( \frac{z-a_0}{a_m-a_0} \right)^{k_n} $$

For an appropriate choice of the set 0f $k$. Any two such functions differ by an entier function.

With all multiplicities equal to 1 the exponents $n_m$ disapear.

Comment: Oh this is a bit too advanced for me :) thank you regardless, I'll learn more about this topic. What could be the actual Weierstrass factorisation of the function then?

Comment: @Lithium your proposed factorization are definitely a good starting point. You then need to check it exponential factors are needed to achieve convergence (since it's a little tricky to get infinite products to converge sometimes), and there might be a polynomial out in front. Any good complex analysis book will cover the details, e.g. Ahlfors, and iirc Wikipedia has a lot of the details.